# Typo3 use multiple template backend objects on single page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a template with some modifications to the root templates base layout, and a custom object only used on that page, that has to be defined via typoscript.

```
# Some modifications to base page layout
page.some.actual.page.tree = < lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement
page.some.unecessary.element >
... some more modifications to page

# stage left enter custom object
lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement = COA
lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = SomeFancyContent
  20 = TEXT
  20.value = MoreFancyContent
}
```

I would like to split the custom Object into it's own separate object, to make reading the templates easier. That way the template objects that actually change the page are a lot shorter, thus making understanding of the pages structure and debugging easier.
I have found if I just split the template object in two, it seems only the first one is used.

I split the template into the objects

+ext:

```
page.some.actual.page.tree = < lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement
page.some.unecessary.element >
... some more modifications to page
```

fancyelement:

```
lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement = COA
lib.someLogicallySeparateDesignElement {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = SomeFancyContent
  20 = TEXT
  20.value = MoreFancyContent
}
```

If +ext is the first template in the backend section for templates under `Web > List`, then the fancyelement is missing, but all other changes of +ext are applied. I reversed the order (I also tried just switching the sorting values in the sys_template table to make sure nothing else is changed) and the changes made in +ext where not applied to the page, leaving just the templates of parent pages. But when I include `fancyelement` in a template of a parent page, it is available

To me it looks like only the first template is used, while all others for that page are discarded.

I do not understand the use of this behaviour, why allow creating an arbitrary amount of templates with custom ordering and dexcriptive titles shown in the backend, when only one can be used?

Is there any way to get a different behaviour for this, like internally concatenating all templates, or inheriting them into each other like templates of parent pages?

**Edit:**

The `Include Basis Template` list on the `Includes` tab while editing a template allows to include other backend template objects.

Including the other templates in that list on the first template will apply all of them.

Comment: For debugging TypoScript, the Template › TypoScript object browser is helpful. It seems you are using additional TypoScript records in the database ("extension templates", +ext)? Nowadays more and more sites use the "sitepackage" concept https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/9.5/en-us/TypoScriptConfiguration/Index.html where loading order is much more explicit and you can use multiple files with @imports. The question seems very broad like that. I would have many questions before being able to answer. For example what do you want to achieve with `page.some.actual.page.tree`?

Comment: I am currently dealing with a pretty messy website I inherited. The name "+ext" is one of the things I inherited and never got around to changing. There is definitely not a single template in our sitepackage, currently alle the templates are in the backend. `page.some.actual.page.tree` is some basic tree where like 10 different objects, like footer, Navbar, etc. reside. If a page has no navbar, that is currently changed there. I am in the process of moving those large objects into `lib`. @imports sounds interesting, but I'd like to be able to see and edit them in the backend.

Comment: I have looked into @imports now, but it appears they are meant for files only. Otherwise it would be a good option for what I'm trying to do, thanks. It seems I misunderstood the use of "Include Basis Template" though, those appear to be what I'm looking for. The only grain of salt is it's another thing to keep track of. If another admin takes over, I guarantee the first new template he creates will not be included, because he doesn't know about that list. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction though

Answer (score 0):

while the TSOB (TypoScriptObjectBrowser) tries(!) to give a state of the typoscript of this page your reference should be the Template Analyzer (the last entry in the drop down)

The problem of the TSOB is, that you need to set all conditions by hand and if you change the page the conditions might need an adaption.

In the Template Analyzer you can show all typoscript (there is a button) and then you can see the order of setting and unsetting. You also see all includes in the order of inclusion.

You also need to know how copying, referencing and deleting is done if your typoscript contains such.
Especially the referencing can have some not so nice side-effects.

`<` is copying the current state of an object, including all subentries. changes to the origin, done afterwards are not included in the copy target.

`=<` references are like a symlink in filesystem, it includes the whole subtree. every change you do either in original or reference is mirrored to the other side. or multiple sides if you reference more often.

`>` deleting removes all entries and subentries

`=` assignes one single value (no subtree!)

---

Another option to inspect the current typoscript of a page is the adminpanel in front end. Here TYPO3 has build the currently active typoscript which is evaluated for this page, with this parameters.

---

and BTW: if you have multiple extension templates on a page, only the last is active. others are ignored (view with Template Analyzer)